# What do I have to do to hit Death with a pumpkin?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

I cannot seem to figure out how to hit Death with the pumpkins on the Lovegood's Lunacy board of *LEGO Harry Potter Years 5-7*.  Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?  I can pick them up, spin them and throw them but they don't get near the grimm.  They're all really weak throws.  I'm playing on the Wii.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After donning your invisibility cloak and sneaking across the screen you will encounter a pumpkin which can be levitated.

On the Wii this is accomplished with <kbd>Z</kbd> on the nunchuck.  To get the pumpkin rotating you press in a direction.  If you press it any direction but straight to the left you will get the weak throws.  Pressing left will magic-bullet-targetting-system onto Death and you can bean him.

I'm advised that this problem on the Xbox involves using the <kbd>B</kbd> button, not the <kbd>X</kbd> button, to pick up the pumpkin in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Pick up pumpkins with <kbd>Z</kbd> button, hold <kbd>Z</kbd> while spinning with nunchuck forward. Release <kbd>Z</kbd> button while pointing the nunchuck's analog stick to the left. The left direction is key here.

Answer (score 1):

Aim to the left with the nunckuk all the way and wait, it will fly over and hit him.